# How can I create photo thumbnails?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

How can I create Photo Thumbnails like this?

[image: Sketch]

Answer (score 2):

For creating thumbnails have a look at the category presented here:

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

And for the view, just make your own **UIScrollView**, or use a **UITableView** with several images per table cell. There are also some (sometimes quite big) packages around you can use, like this here - they have the full functionality of thumbnail views:

http://three20.info/

Comment: three20 gives me warnings when I added on iOS 5, take a look http://i.stack.imgur.com/LGxGp.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/8tCip.png

Comment: you'll find that with quite a lot of code you will find on the internet now,as iOs 5 is quite new and not all classes are or will  be updated - you'll have to wait for an update or do some changes yourself then

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a UIView and place UIImages in it. The ammount of images should be computed depending the hardware (iphone, retina, ipad, etc)
There is no ready-made view to stack elememnts (UIImages) like in the c#